# doctrine:generate:entities vs generate:doctrine:entities in Symfony2 console

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

What are the differences between

```
doctrine:generate:entities vs generate:doctrine:entities
```

the description for both is the same

```
Generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same.

`generate:doctrine:entities` is an alias to `doctrine:generate:entities`

In the DoctrineBundle source code it is coded as:

```
...
$this
    ->setName('doctrine:generate:entities')
    ->setAliases(array('generate:doctrine:entities'))
...
```

[Source code link.](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php)